# React Slick disable text dragging and auto click on drag when links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

Im using React-Slick for my carouse/Slider , it works normally at first but when you added a link property to it(move to an url when the object inside it is clicked), the text inside that object became draggable , and also by just dragging the slider, the click automatically fires up, making dragging useless. How should I fix this?

```
 <Slider {...settingsfeatured}>
      <Link to={`/url`} >
             <p> Sliding </p>

  </Slider>
```

alternative carousel package will also be fine for me